# Salvar registro no banco com entity

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Caros colegas.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicacao `C#` `Winform` com banco de dados `SqlServer` e `Entity framework`.
Como sou inexperiente, venho tomando conhecimento através da internet.
Estou com uma dificuldade de entender e implementar alguns conceitos em relação a orientação a objetos em relação manipulação do banco de dados.

Colocarei abaixo as partes do meu sistema para ver se podem me ajudar a tornar este código funcional. Para ser mais objetivo, meu código até que estava funcionando porém sem os devidos relacionamentos entre as tabelas. Quando o modifiquei para que as tabelas tivessem relacionamentos começou dar erros, conforme este a seguir.

Agradeço a ajuda.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
>     HResult=0x80131501
>     Message=Entities in 'BancoContexto.PedidoCtx' participate in the 'Cliente_PedidoPrincipalX' relationship. 0 related 
>   'Cliente_PedidoPrincipalX_Source' were found. 1 'Cliente_PedidoPrincipalX_Source' is expected.

```
namespace DAL.MODEL
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public Cliente()
        {
            this.PedidoPrincipalX = new List<PedidoPrincipal>();
        }

        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PedidoPrincipal> PedidoPrincipalX { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace DAL.MODEL
{
    public class PedidoPrincipal
    {
        public int PedidoId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataEmissao { get; set; }
        public Decimal Total { get; set; }

        public int FK_ClienteId { get; set; }
        public virtual Cliente ClienteX { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace DAL.MAPPING
{
    public class ClienteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
    {
        public ClienteMap()
        {
            ToTable("Cliente");
            HasKey(c => c.ClienteId);
            Property(c => c.ClienteId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            HasMany(X => X.PedidoPrincipalX);
        }
    }
}


namespace DAL.MAPPING
{
    public class PedidoPrincipalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PedidoPrincipal>
    {
        public PedidoPrincipalMap()
        {
            ToTable("PedidoPrincipal");
            HasKey(p => p.PedidoId);
            Property(p => p.PedidoId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            HasRequired(X => X.ClienteX);
        }
    }
}
```

**Trecho do código para salvar no banco:**

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PedidoPrincipalRepositorio app = new PedidoPrincipalRepositorio();

    PedidoPrincipal pedido = new PedidoPrincipal();

    pedido.FK_ClienteId = Int32.Parse(txtCodigoCli.Text);

    pedido.DataEmissao = DateTime.Now;
    pedido.Total = decimal.Parse(txtValorTotal.Text);

    app.Adicionar(pedido);
    app.SalvarTodos();
}
```

Comment: Você está usando CodeFirst? se sim, você tem liberdade de definir os nomes dos campos e os relacionamentos? digo isso pois com CodeFirst tem uma forma muito simples de fazer o relacionamento, que irá te ajudar inclusive com o CRUD

Comment: Sim Rodrigo. Estou usando CodeFirst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro faremos algumas mudanças no seu Model, para facilitar a sua vida, usaremos as [convenções](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx) do *Code First*.

```
namespace DAL.MODEL{

    public class Cliente
    {
        public Cliente()
        {
            this.PedidoPrincipalX = new List<PedidoPrincipal>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PedidoPrincipal> PedidoPrincipalX { get; set;} 
    }
}
```

**Modificações**

- Substitui `public int ClienteId { get; set; }`por `public int Id { get; set; }`, desta forma passamos a usar a conversão do *EF*, sendo assim ele passa a entender que ID é a chave primária da entidade *Cliente*, e usará essa mesma chave como *FK*, nos seus relacionamentos

---

```
namespace DAL.MODEL
{
    public class PedidoPrincipal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataEmissao { get; set; }
        public Decimal Total { get; set; }
        public int ClienteId {get;set;}

        public virtual Cliente ClienteX { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Modificações:**

- Substitui `public int PedidoId { get; set; }` por public int Id { get; set; }`, pelo menos motivo de cima, para manter a convenção, desta forma o simples fato de usar as propriedades virtuais, fará com que o *EF* entenda o relacionamento de forma automátiva
- Removi `public int FK_ClienteId { get; set; }`, pois pelo fato de adotarmos as convenções do *EF*, essa propriedade se torna desnecessária, e pode até atrapalhar o *EF*.
- Inclui `public int ClienteId {get;set;}`, substituindo a propriedade removida, assim você pode usa-la para ligar o cliente ao pedido.
  Obs: Deve-se seguir o padrão de escrita, {nome da classe+Id}, assim o EF, irá identificar essa propriedades como `FK`.

---

**Bem, agora que resolvemos o model, vamos aos *Mappings*:**

```
namespace DAL.MAPPING{

    public class ClienteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
    {
        public ClienteMap(){
            Property(c => c.ClienteId)
              .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }
}


namespace DAL.MAPPING
{
    public class PedidoPrincipalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PedidoPrincipal>{
        public PedidoPrincipalMap()
        {
            Property(p => p.PedidoId)                   
               .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        }
    }
 }
```

**Modificações:**

- Deixamos apenas a configuração de `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption`, pois como disse acima, usando as convenções do *EF*, toda a parte de relacionamento já é criada automaticamente, assim se torna desnecessário essa configuração por *Fluent Api*.

---

Desta forma o seu código fica limpo, fácil de entender, e diminuir essas chances de erros com relacionamento. O link que passei sobre as convenções também tem vários tutoriais sobre coisas que você irá precisar, acho uma boa, vai te ajudar muito neste inicio, foi o que eu usei como fonte de estudo para aprender.

Comment: Obrigado Rodrigo. Irei implementar.

Comment: Olá Rodrigo.

Agora está gravando no banco, mas surgiu um outro problema. Nesta parte da aplicação, é uma tela de pedidos, preciso informar um cliente já está cadastrado, isto  está Ok, e cadastrar um pedido para o cliente. O problema é, p/ localizar o cliente no banco, criei uma instancia do cliente, e fiz a busca no banco. Agora preencho os dados do pedido na tela p/ gravar no banco. Tem um relacionamento com a tabela de clientes, mas não esta salvando o cliente na tabela de pedidos. Depois de salvar o pedido, na tabela a coluna onde deveria constar o código do cliente fica NULL.

Comment: Desculpe, foi falha minha, incluir na classe `PedidoPrincipal` a propriedade `public int ClienteId {get;set;}`, agora basta preencher com o id do cliente. Obs: Tem que ser exatamente neste padrão {nome da Classe+Id}, para seguir as convenções, desta forma o EF entende essa propriedades como a chave estrangeira para `Cliente`.